# type object 'User' has no attribute 'is_staff' in Django Application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing, django-users

if you see the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#user), they have given that `User` object has an attribute `is_staff`. I am trying to see what is the default value of `is_staff` when we create a new user in unit testing. The code is fairly very simple:

```
def test_login_user(self):
        User.objects.create_user('john', 'example@abc.edu', 'password')
        print self.client.login(username='john', password='password')
        print User.is_staff
        if User.is_staff:
            s = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/')
        else:
            s = HttpResponseForbidden()
        print s.status_code
```

Now when I try to print out `print User.is_staff`, it is showing

> type object 'User' has no attribute 'is_staff' in Django Application

I already know the user is not staff user so the output of `User.is_staff` should be `False` right? Could anyone point out where I am wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You should check class instance, not class:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'example@abc.edu', 'password')
if user.is_staff:
    <do something>
```

Comment: Do you know about `RequireStaffMixinView` ? Why it is used ?

Comment: Nope. I think it's part of your project, i.e. not part of Django. But how it's related to your question?

Comment: Learning Django :) got confused. Thanks for your answer